# How to know last boot up time for fast boot settings

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was using WMI to get the last boot date/time. But with fast boot enabled, boot up time is not reset and thus I am not getting what I expected. How can I know if it got booted(may not be cold shutdown) in C#? I have seen powershell command that lists boot up time and type(it didn't work when i tried in powershell). I don't know how to do it in C# or some other way is there to know it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to learn from that boot time?

Comment: After some software installI, have marked a file to be deleted after reboot. Thus user can reboot later. If the file gets deleted, means that user has done reboot.
For that I am using MoveFileEX delay until reboot flag. With fast boot, this doesn't seem to work.
Some times that move file doesn't work. So we had workaround of checking bootup time and file creation time. If bootup time is after file creation, means user did reboot and movefile didn't delete, we delete it and mark software install is done...

Comment: ...I think software needing reboot works in case of fast boot(might be wrong). If it works with fast boot, I need to figure it out how to handle the case

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); you're not looking for the reboot time. You're looking for a way to check if these files were handled. MoveFileEx [adds the file into a "to be deleted" list in the registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa#remarks), at `HKLM > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Session Manager > PendingFileRenameOperations`. You should simply be able to check that list, and compare it with your program's list of files that had to be deleted on reboot, to see if they have all been handled.